# How do I print these lines horizontally

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I'm trying to print these numbers (in the form of a digital clock) all on the same line. My goal is to have a function take in a few numbers and print them all on the same line.

```
numbers = {
0: 
[
    
' _ ',
'| |',
'|_|'

],
1: 
[
    
'   ',
'| |',
'| |'
]
}


for k, v in numbers.items():
    for i in range(len(numbers)+1):
        print(v[i])
```

This will print a number, for example, but the next one is on the next line down.

If I add end="" at the end of the print statement, the number doesn't appear properly.
Ty

Comment: don't be thinking `print numbers all on the same line` ... that's incorrect ... be thinking `print numbers on three consecutive lines` ... the solution may crystallize in your mind

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = {
    0:
        [
            ' _ ',
            '| |',
            '|_|'
        ],
    1:
        [
            ' /|',
            '  |',
            '  |'
        ],
    2:
        [
            '!--',
            ' / ',
            '|__ '
        ]
}

lines = [''] * 3
for k, v in numbers.items():
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        lines[i] += v[i] + '   '

for l in lines:
    print(l)
```

Prints:

```
 _     /|   !--   
| |     |    /    
|_|     |   |__
```

Comment: you are a genius i would have never come up with this. how would you make this a function that converts any number into the displayed nums from above

Answer (score 1):

I propose a slightly different approach to this task. First create a whole line of text to be printed (consisting of a concatenation of the individual elements of all the numbers), and then print it.

```
for i in range(3):
    output = ""
    for k, v in numbers.items():
        output += v[i]
    print(output)
```

### Update

To print specific set of numbers using a function you need to iterate through the input variable (not through numbers.items()).

An example function:

```py
def printit(string):
    for i in range(3):
        output = ""
        for num in string:
            output += numbers[int(num)][i]
        print(output)
        
printit('01')
```

Comment: ty however if i convert this to a function, the logic doesn't work since the function is meant to output the numbers in the clock format (but we are talking about the numbers input into the function, not necessarily all the items in the dictionary). In our case though we only have 2 numbers but I can add more

Comment: Could you show me the code of your function?

Comment: `def printit(string):

    output = ""
    for i in range(len(string)+1):
        for k, v in numbers.items():
        
            output += v[i]
        print(output)
printit('12')`

Comment: Because, as you yourself mentioned "we are talking about the numbers input into the function, not necessarily all the items in the dictionary", in the printit function you need to do a for loop through the string input variable (not through numbers.items).

After a few changes, the function looks like it works fine:

```python
def printit(string):
    for i in range(3):
        output = ""
        for num in string:
            output += numbers[int(num)][i]
        print(output)

Comment: yeah you are correct, that is what i was able to work through to get, ty

Comment: I have edited my main answer and put there the code of my example function from the comment.

I think it will be much more readable this way :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Python3, you can use

```
for k, v in numbers.items():
   for i in range(len(numbers)+1):
      print(v[i], end = "")
```

to print inline. You can additional add a symbol inside the end string to separate items.

Comment: I tried that but the problem is the number comes out all jumbled and not in the correct format

Comment: yeah that is correct

Comment: Wonderful. It looks the other answers have solved your problem, but hopefully my hint on inline printing comes in handy sometime!

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)!

```
numbers = {0: [' _ ',
               '| |',
               '|_|'],
           1: ['   ',
               '  |',
               '  |'],
           2: [' _ ',
               ' _|',
               '|_ ']}

target = '0120'

print('\n'.join([' '.join(x) for x in zip(*(numbers[int(x)] for x in target))]))
```

output:

```
 _       _   _ 
| |   |  _| | |
|_|   | |_  |_|
```